# Find Root condition for polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, code-review

I have the following 12-th order polynomial in $\lambda$ with a parameter dependency in $u$:

```
    poly=3.758812241612053*10^13 u^6 + 66684.040550135 u^8 + 
 20.49586406017019 u^10 + 6.12991545011170*10^14 u^5 λ + 
 6.01167537443016*10^10 u^7 λ + 
 1914.48298091448 u^9 λ - 
 0.00267379855125686 u^11 λ + 
 3.814290619807640*10^15 u^4 λ^2 + 
 9.75191746950487*10^11 u^6 λ^2 - 
 949716.524761391 u^8 λ^2 - 
 0.0954589106310578 u^10 λ^2 + 
 1.128013473957935*10^16 u^3 λ^3 + 
 6.38428561704187*10^12 u^5 λ^3 - 
 1.262277888152881*10^7 u^7 λ^3 - 
 1.160245217815036 u^9 λ^3 + 
 1.631286280022314*10^16 u^2 λ^4 + 
 2.191981230195581*10^13 u^4 λ^4 - 
 5.36371908111549*10^7 u^6 λ^4 - 
 6.51903956301006 u^8 λ^4 + 
 1.121169470558621*10^16 u λ^5 + 
 4.286884095504253*10^13 u^3 λ^5 - 
 4.17354307569272*10^7 u^5 λ^5 - 
 17.97352149064410 u^7 λ^5 + 
 2.939985093295978*10^15 λ^6 + 
 4.77561461786877*10^13 u^2 λ^6 + 
 2.782169805785492*10^8 u^4 λ^6 - 
 20.17952007466918 u^6 λ^6 + 
 2.806695934260627*10^13 u λ^7 + 
 7.88988982463672*10^8 u^3 λ^7 + 
 10.15936451642606 u^5 λ^7 + 
 6.72945116203121*10^12 λ^8 + 
 8.60548557130742*10^8 u^2 λ^8 + 
 54.6841649927119 u^4 λ^8 + 
 4.333744253932484*10^8 u λ^9 + 
 64.3095129804413 u^3 λ^9 + 
 8.38630477586613*10^7 λ^10 + 
 36.39409592503903 u^2 λ^10 + 
 9.95454310398946 u λ^11 + λ^12;
```

I would like to find the condition for $u$ in order that there exists a root on the imaginary axis. 
I've tried this code:

```
Reduce[poly == 0 && Re[λ] == 0, λ]
```

Note: **u is a positive number (not zero)**.
It is taking a lot of time, understandably. Is this the best way to solve this?

Comment: You say exact condition on $u$ but all your coefficients are inexact. How do you expect that to work?

Comment: `u == 0` yields `λ == 0`, which is on the imaginary axis.

Comment: You're right. It won't be exact, I'll edit my post.

Comment: Can $u$ be complex?

Comment: No, u is a real number and positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
poly = 3.758812241612053*10^13 u^6 + 66684.040550135 u^8 + 
   20.49586406017019 u^10 + 6.12991545011170*10^14 u^5 lam + 
   6.01167537443016*10^10 u^7 lam + 1914.48298091448 u^9 lam - 
   0.00267379855125686 u^11 lam + 3.814290619807640*10^15 u^4 lam^2 + 
   9.75191746950487*10^11 u^6 lam^2 - 949716.524761391 u^8 lam^2 - 
   0.0954589106310578 u^10 lam^2 + 
   1.128013473957935*10^16 u^3 lam^3 + 
   6.38428561704187*10^12 u^5 lam^3 - 
   1.262277888152881*10^7 u^7 lam^3 - 1.160245217815036 u^9 lam^3 + 
   1.631286280022314*10^16 u^2 lam^4 + 
   2.191981230195581*10^13 u^4 lam^4 - 
   5.36371908111549*10^7 u^6 lam^4 - 6.51903956301006 u^8 lam^4 + 
   1.121169470558621*10^16 u lam^5 + 
   4.286884095504253*10^13 u^3 lam^5 - 
   4.17354307569272*10^7 u^5 lam^5 - 17.97352149064410 u^7 lam^5 + 
   2.939985093295978*10^15 lam^6 + 4.77561461786877*10^13 u^2 lam^6 + 
   2.782169805785492*10^8 u^4 lam^6 - 20.17952007466918 u^6 lam^6 + 
   2.806695934260627*10^13 u lam^7 + 
   7.88988982463672*10^8 u^3 lam^7 + 10.15936451642606 u^5 lam^7 + 
   6.72945116203121*10^12 lam^8 + 8.60548557130742*10^8 u^2 lam^8 + 
   54.6841649927119 u^4 lam^8 + 4.333744253932484*10^8 u lam^9 + 
   64.3095129804413 u^3 lam^9 + 8.38630477586613*10^7 lam^10 + 
   36.39409592503903 u^2 lam^10 + 9.95454310398946 u lam^11 + lam^12;
```

Split the variable into explicit real and imaginary parts, and we will insist that the real and imaginary parts of the polynomial that results both vanish.

```
polyReIm = poly /. {lam -> re + I*im};
cpolys = ComplexExpand[{Re[polyReIm], Im[polyReIm]}];
```

We also want the real part of the variable to vanish.

```
realSolns = Solve[Flatten[{cpolys, re}] == 0, {re, im, u}, Reals];
posSolns = Select[realSolns, ((im /. #) > 0) &]

During evaluation of In[187]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

(* Out[188]= {{re -> 0, im -> 20.9592029375, u -> 0}, {re -> 0, 
  im -> 154.502486303, u -> -252.449563342}, {re -> 0, 
  im -> 154.502486303, u -> 252.449563342}, {re -> 0, 
  im -> 282.631493317, u -> 0}, {re -> 0, im -> 9153.29055091, 
  u -> 0}} *)
```

So that gives both roots and the corresponding values for the parameter.

Comment: Nicely done(+1).  A more compact formulation is `Reduce[{Simplify[
ReIm@ComplexExpand[poly /. λ -> I m], (u | m) ∈ Reals] == 0, u > 0}, {u, m}, Reals]`.

Comment: @bgodfrey Thanks, I keep forgetting about `ReIm`. Which is ironic since it is a function I had suggested we add a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a purely imaginary root $\lambda = \sqrt{-1} m = i m$ gives

```
Chop @ ComplexExpand[poly /. λ -> I m]

-2.93999*10^15 m^6 + 6.72945*10^12 m^8 - 8.3863*10^7 m^10 + m^12 + 
 1.63129*10^16 m^4 u^2 - 4.77561*10^13 m^6 u^2 + 
 8.60549*10^8 m^8 u^2 - 36.3941 m^10 u^2 - 3.81429*10^15 m^2 u^4 + 
 2.19198*10^13 m^4 u^4 - 2.78217*10^8 m^6 u^4 + 54.6842 m^8 u^4 + 
 3.75881*10^13 u^6 - 9.75192*10^11 m^2 u^6 - 5.36372*10^7 m^4 u^6 + 
 20.1795 m^6 u^6 + 66684. u^8 + 949717. m^2 u^8 - 6.51904 m^4 u^8 + 
 20.4959 u^10 + 0.0954589 m^2 u^10 + 
 I (1.12117*10^16 m^5 u - 2.8067*10^13 m^7 u + 4.33374*10^8 m^9 u - 
    9.95454 m^11 u - 1.12801*10^16 m^3 u^3 + 4.28688*10^13 m^5 u^3 - 
    7.88989*10^8 m^7 u^3 + 64.3095 m^9 u^3 + 6.12992*10^14 m u^5 - 
    6.38429*10^12 m^3 u^5 - 4.17354*10^7 m^5 u^5 - 10.1594 m^7 u^5 + 
    6.01168*10^10 m u^7 + 1.26228*10^7 m^3 u^7 - 17.9735 m^5 u^7 + 
    1914.48 m u^9 + 1.16025 m^3 u^9 - 0.0026738 m u^11)
```

which we can do since $u$ is assumed real. We store the real and imaginary parts of this expression separately:

```
re = -2.93999*10^15 m^6 + 6.72945*10^12 m^8 - 8.3863*10^7 m^10 + m^12 + 
 1.63129*10^16 m^4 u^2 - 4.77561*10^13 m^6 u^2 + 
 8.60549*10^8 m^8 u^2 - 36.3941 m^10 u^2 - 3.81429*10^15 m^2 u^4 + 
 2.19198*10^13 m^4 u^4 - 2.78217*10^8 m^6 u^4 + 54.6842 m^8 u^4 + 
 3.75881*10^13 u^6 - 9.75192*10^11 m^2 u^6 - 5.36372*10^7 m^4 u^6 + 
 20.1795 m^6 u^6 + 66684. u^8 + 949717. m^2 u^8 - 6.51904 m^4 u^8 + 
 20.4959 u^10 + 0.0954589 m^2 u^10;

im = 1.12117*10^16 m^5 u - 2.8067*10^13 m^7 u + 4.33374*10^8 m^9 u - 
    9.95454 m^11 u - 1.12801*10^16 m^3 u^3 + 4.28688*10^13 m^5 u^3 - 
    7.88989*10^8 m^7 u^3 + 64.3095 m^9 u^3 + 6.12992*10^14 m u^5 - 
    6.38429*10^12 m^3 u^5 - 4.17354*10^7 m^5 u^5 - 10.1594 m^7 u^5 + 
    6.01168*10^10 m u^7 + 1.26228*10^7 m^3 u^7 - 17.9735 m^5 u^7 + 
    1914.48 m u^9 + 1.16025 m^3 u^9 - 0.0026738 m u^11;
```

For $im$ to be a root of the polynomial we must demand that the real and imaginary parts are 0 separately. We find

```
Reduce[re == 0 && im == 0]

(u == 0 && 
   m == 0) || (u == 
    0 && (m == 0 || m == -20.9592 || m == 20.9592 || m == -282.631 || 
     m == 282.631 || m == -9153.29 || m == 9153.29)) || ((u == 0 || 
     u == 822.375 - 823.364 I || u == -822.375 + 823.364 I || 
     u == -822.375 - 823.364 I || u == 822.375 + 823.364 I) && 
   m == 0) || ((u == 0. - 26910.2 I || u == 0. + 26910.2 I || 
     u == 0. - 4113.37 I || u == 0. + 4113.37 I || 
     u == 0. - 3923.92 I || u == 0. + 3923.92 I || 
     u == 0. - 3004.75 I || u == 0. + 3004.75 I || 
     u == 0. - 2561.45 I || u == 0. + 2561.45 I || 
     u == 0. - 2106.71 I || u == 0. + 2106.71 I || 
     u == 0. - 237.693 I || u == 0. + 237.693 I || 
     u == 0. - 50.3109 I || u == 0. + 50.3109 I || 
     u == 0. - 49.0353 I || u == 0. + 49.0353 I || 
     u == 0. - 44.402 I || u == 0. + 44.402 I || u == 0. - 17.0771 I ||
      u == 0. + 17.0771 I || u == 0. - 16.3543 I || 
     u == 0. + 16.3543 I || u == 0. - 14.4941 I || 
     u == 0. + 14.4941 I || u == -252.45 || u == 252.45 || 
     u == -836.92 || u == 836.92 || u == -839.43 || u == 839.43 || 
     u == -925.894 || u == 925.894 || u == -2248.77 || u == 2248.77 ||
      u == -432.629 + 3616.74 I || u == 432.629 - 3616.74 I || 
     u == -432.629 - 3616.74 I || u == 432.629 + 3616.74 I || 
     u == -132.115 + 2412.91 I || u == 132.115 - 2412.91 I || 
     u == -132.115 - 2412.91 I || u == 132.115 + 2412.91 I || 
     u == -18.4148 + 246.491 I || u == 18.4148 - 246.491 I || 
     u == -18.4148 - 246.491 I || 
     u == 18.4148 + 
       246.491 I) && (m == -1.005208931810471*10^-4817 \
√(7.006345301190785*10^9632 u^2 + 
          3.974774954841963*10^9632 u^4 + 
          2.564599329062603*10^9630 u^6 + 
          5.935134409204949*10^9627 u^8 + 
          5.275185373232790*10^9624 u^10 + 
          2.027095913001037*10^9621 u^12 + 
          3.040827073402816*10^9617 u^14 + 
          7.554740567036133*10^9612 u^16 - 
          2.844773495797010*10^9607 u^18 - 
          2.192246534572371*10^9603 u^20 - 
          1.139653113847781*10^9598 u^22 + 
          5.240645403518338*10^9592 u^24 - 
          3.996899261757150*10^9586 u^26 - 
          2.179470396706121*10^9580 u^28 + 
          1.299937619639369*10^9574 u^30 + 
          9.49998330164809*10^9567 u^32 + 
          1.910804986606984*10^9561 u^34 + 
          4.575072505742353*10^9552 u^36 - 
          6.193851941240428*10^9547 u^38 - 
          1.194394185335309*10^9541 u^40 - 
          1.136546280278521*10^9534 u^42 - 
          6.123770596467873*10^9526 u^44 - 
          1.799480590522928*10^9519 u^46 - 
          2.317293259841171*10^9511 u^48 - 
          2.872545702269800*10^9502 u^50) || 
     m == 1.005208931810471*10^-4817 \
√(7.006345301190785*10^9632 u^2 + 
          3.974774954841963*10^9632 u^4 + 
          2.564599329062603*10^9630 u^6 + 
          5.935134409204949*10^9627 u^8 + 
          5.275185373232790*10^9624 u^10 + 
          2.027095913001037*10^9621 u^12 + 
          3.040827073402816*10^9617 u^14 + 
          7.554740567036133*10^9612 u^16 - 
          2.844773495797010*10^9607 u^18 - 
          2.192246534572371*10^9603 u^20 - 
          1.139653113847781*10^9598 u^22 + 
          5.240645403518338*10^9592 u^24 - 
          3.996899261757150*10^9586 u^26 - 
          2.179470396706121*10^9580 u^28 + 
          1.299937619639369*10^9574 u^30 + 
          9.49998330164809*10^9567 u^32 + 
          1.910804986606984*10^9561 u^34 + 
          4.575072505742353*10^9552 u^36 - 
          6.193851941240428*10^9547 u^38 - 
          1.194394185335309*10^9541 u^40 - 
          1.136546280278521*10^9534 u^42 - 
          6.123770596467873*10^9526 u^44 - 
          1.799480590522928*10^9519 u^46 - 
          2.317293259841171*10^9511 u^48 - 
          2.872545702269800*10^9502 u^50)))
```

Adding the fact that $m$ must be real and $u$ positive, we only find

```
Reduce[re == 0 && im == 0 && m ∈ Reals && u > 0]
(u == 252.45 && m == -154.502) || (u == 252.45 && m == 154.502)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with $im$ and $re$. Would you add how you obtained them?